# Custom shape to UISlider and update progress in Swift 5

Tags: swift, uiview, swift5, uislider

I have checked some of the StackOverflow answers regarding custom UIView slider but using them I unable to make the slider like this. This makes a circle or half circle. I have figured out some library that makes circle slider using UIView but its not helpful to me so could anyone please help me out. How can I make slider like in below UIImage? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will probably just roll your own. (You obviously could search for third party implementations, but that would be out of scope for StackOverflow.) There are a lot of ways of tackling this, but the basic elements here are:

1. The pink arc for the overall path. Personally, I'd use a `CAShapeLayer` for that.
2. The white arc from the start to the current progress (measured from 0 to 1). Again, a `CAShapeLayer` would be logical.
3. The white dot placed at the spot of the current progress. Below I create a `CALayer` with white background and then apply a `CAGradientLayer` as a mask to that. You could also just create a `UIImage` for this.
4. In terms of how to set the progress, you would set the paths of the pink and white arcs to the same path, but just update the `strokeEnd` of the white arc. You would also adjust the position of the white dot layer accordingly.
5. The only complicated thing here is figuring out the center of the arc. In my example below, I calculate it with some trigonometry based upon the bounds of the view so that arc goes from lower left corner, to the top, and back down the the lower right corner. Or you might instead pass the center of the arc as a parameter.

Anyway, it might look like:

```swift
@IBDesignable
class ArcView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable
    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 7 { didSet { updatePaths() } }

    @IBInspectable
    var progress: CGFloat = 0 { didSet { updatePaths() } }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

        progress = 0.35
    }

    lazy var currentPositionDotLayer: CALayer = {
        let layer = CALayer()
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: lineWidth * 3, height: lineWidth * 3)
        layer.frame = rect

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.type = .radial
        gradientLayer.frame = rect
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.5, 1]

        layer.mask = gradientLayer

        return layer
    }()

    lazy var progressShapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        return shapeLayer
    }()

    lazy var totalShapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9439327121, green: 0.5454334617, blue: 0.6426400542, alpha: 1)
        return shapeLayer
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configure()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updatePaths()
    }
}

// MARK: - Private utility methods

private extension ArcView {

    func configure() {
        layer.addSublayer(totalShapeLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(progressShapeLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(currentPositionDotLayer)
    }

    func updatePaths() {
        let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth / 2, dy: lineWidth / 2)
        let halfWidth = rect.width / 2
        let height = rect.height
        let theta = atan(halfWidth / height)
        let radius = sqrt(halfWidth * halfWidth + height * height) / 2 / cos(theta)
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY + radius)
        let delta = (.pi / 2 - theta) * 2
        let startAngle = .pi * 3 / 2 - delta
        let endAngle = .pi * 3 / 2 + delta

        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                                radius: radius,
                                startAngle: startAngle,
                                endAngle: endAngle,
                                clockwise: true)

        progressShapeLayer.path = path.cgPath // white arc
        totalShapeLayer.path = path.cgPath    // pink arc
        progressShapeLayer.strokeEnd = progress

        let currentAngle = (endAngle - startAngle) * progress + startAngle
        let dotCenter = CGPoint(x: center.x + radius * cos(currentAngle),
                                y: center.y + radius * sin(currentAngle))
        currentPositionDotLayer.position = dotCenter
    }
}
```

[image]

Above, I set the background color of the `ArcView` so you could see its `bounds`, but you would obviously set the background color to be transparent.

Now there are tons of additional features you might add (e.g. add user interaction so you could “scrub” it, etc.). See https://github.com/robertmryan/ArcView for example. But the key when designing this sort of stuff is to just break it down into its constituent elements, layering one on top of the other.

---

You can programmatically set the `progress` of the `arcView` to get it to change the current value between values of 0 and 1:

```swift
func startUpdating() {
    arcView.progress = 0

    var current = 0

    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
        current += 1

        guard let self = self, current <= 10 else {
            timer.invalidate()
            return
        }

        self.arcView.progress = CGFloat(current) / 10
    }
}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Hello @Rob, Thank you so much for your time. I added this code to my project everything works fine but facing one issue out progress = 0.35 but it showing me at 0. If I change this progress value in storyboard then it works not programmatically it not working?

Comment: I checked prepareForInterfaceBuilder this method is not calling.

Comment: Hello @Rob, I am facing some issue with moving progress can you please help me with this. I try with UIView Touch action but always getting CALayer and confuse about the need to add a position or what? and also trying CATransaction but not working.  If you can help me with this then I'll update the question. Thanks!

Comment: Re your question about not updating, I don't know why it wouldn't be updating for you. See this example, shown above in revised answer: https://github.com/robertmryan/ArcView

Comment: @YogeshPatel - Re touches, I just pushed commit showing example of the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. Your GitHub project is working fine.
I am wondering that how can assign min and max value of the slider and also how can I get the current value when touchesEnded in ViewController? Thanks!

Comment: In ArcView can we take two variable for assign max and min?
I checked there is some logic for the white arc in CAShapeLayer so I can't understand how can I achieve that.

Comment: The code calculates the `progress` as a value from 0 to 1. If you want to convert from that to values between `minimum` and `maximum` it is `let value = (maximum - minimum) * progress + minimum`. Likewise, to go the other way, it is `let progress = (value - minimum) / (maximum - minimum)`.

Comment: I don't want to convert suppose we are now assigning our progress value from VC(self.arcView.progress), so How can I assign Max and Min value for slider?

Comment: In UISlider we can assign min and max and if we want to get the current value we use value variable for that I want to do the same thing here Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I just outlined in my prior comment how to, given a minimum and maximum values, how to convert a particular `value` within the range to a point in the progress view, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, @Rob All things working fine now!